# Unknown Error while uploading video using react native firebase

Tags: react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I am using react native firebase library from invertase. While uploading video file using firebase.storage(), I am getting an unknown error. I tried every solution on StackOverflow, still, none of the solutions solved my problem. I am using react native image picker to pick a video from storage.

```js
const options2 = {
  title: 'Select video',
  mediaType: 'video',
  path: 'video',
  quality: 1
};

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options2, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);

  }
  else {
    firebase.storage().ref().child('vid_my')
      .putFile(response.uri, { contentType: 'video/mp4' })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error ' + error)
      })
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot));
      })
  }
});
```

Comment: Try putting your .catch() before the .then()

Comment: Also `.child('vid_my')` needs an extension I believe so try `vid_my.mp4`

Comment: @Badrush I tried it but still getting same error. Can you check if this code is working for you or not.

Comment: I tried updating the react-native-firebase library to v6 and it's working.